# changing values of a data frame according to the continuous intervals of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, range, intervals

I have a large data frame, which is a table of information of my analysis. A subset of that would be like as below:

```
df<-read.table(text="   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
1   id1 id2 (1,2.5) (2.5,4) (4,5.5)
2   a   a   1.5147654   1.5147654   1.5147654
3   a   c   1.97638457  1.97638457  1.97638457
4   c   d   1.55151792  -2.38160971 1.55151792
5   a   b   2.25182522  2.25182522  -1.3523473
6   b   d   1.85349445  1.85349445  1.85349445
",
                 header=TRUE)
```

As it is shown, the forst row of that contains numeric intervals, and I don't know how to read them in R as continuous ranges.

Second, I have multiple tables that I want to make a comparison between their values and this main data frame. For an illustration, a subset of my table is like this:

```
sample<-read.table(text="   V1  V2  V3
               1    a   b   1
               2    a   c   1.5
               3    d   b   3.5
               4    d   c   5.1
               ",
                 header=TRUE)
```

I like to compare the sample with my df, for example, in the first row of sample 'a' is next to 'b' with value '1'. However in df if a is next to be and the value is 1, according to the intervals it must be changed to 2.25182522    in the sample table. The final result would be like :

```
    V1  V2  V3
1   a   b   2.25182522
2   a   c   1.97638457
3   d   b   1.85349445
4   d   c   1.55151792
```

As I have many sample tables and they are large in size, any idea to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is vague to me. But for your second question, I think it is a merge question. The key is to create a merge ID based on the order from `V1` and `V2` of both dataset. The following code based on the package [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) first creates that merge ID and then conducts `left_join`. `df3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Merge_ID = apply(df2[, c("V1", "V2")], 1, 
                          function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = "_"))) %>%
  select(-V3) %>%
  left_join(df1 %>% mutate(
         Merge_ID = apply(df1[, c("V1", "V2")], 1, 
                          function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = "_"))) %>%
           select(Merge_ID, V3),
            by = "Merge_ID") %>%
  select(-Merge_ID) %>%
  mutate(V3 = as.numeric(V3))
df3
#   V1 V2       V3
# 1  a  b 2.251825
# 2  a  c 1.976385
# 3  d  b 1.853494
# 4  d  c 1.551518
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
1   id1 id2 (1,2.5) (2.5,4) (4,5.5)
2   a   a   1.5147654   1.5147654   1.5147654
3   a   c   1.97638457  1.97638457  1.97638457
4   c   d   1.55151792  -2.38160971 1.55151792
5   a   b   2.25182522  2.25182522  -1.3523473
6   b   d   1.85349445  1.85349445  1.85349445
",
               header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text="   V1  V2  V3
               1    a   b   1
               2    a   c   1.5
               3    d   b   3.5
               4    d   c   5.1
               ",
                   header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my first question, there are numeric intervals for each column and in df2 of your solution if the value is for example between 1, 2.5 the replaced value should be chosen from the column of that interval.

Comment: Still not clear. It would be helpful if you can provide a reproducible example and the desire output of your first question.